# python interpretation of / and \ windows and ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have depeloped a flask application that displays information on charts.

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.6
- conda 4.5.4

I have then deployed the application on:

- Ubuntu Server 18.04
- conda 4.5.4
- python 3.6.6

I then try to execute the application but for some reason I get errors on ubuntu that I did not get on windows. One of these errors is regarding the access to files.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/myuser/projects/myflaskappe/mod_on/queries\\prices.sql'
```

I access that file and it is there, the user has permission to access it. 
Then I decide to modify the python code that refers to that document:

```
# original code 
data_objects = {'prices': {
    'sql-path': r'queries\prices.sql',
    'source': 'my_db',
    'flavor': 'mysql'}
    }
```

I have found that if I modify the code from `\` to `/` then it works perfectly.

```
# modified code 
    data_objects = {'prices': {
        'sql-path': r'queries/prices.sql',
        'source': 'my_db',
        'flavor': 'mysql'}
        }
```

If you notice, I have only modify `\` for `/` to make it work.

Why is the reason for this?

There are some other problems as similar to this one that I can't understand why they happen.

Comment: Related: [Difference between forward slash (/) and backslash (\) in file path](//stackoverflow.com/q/38428561)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that Windows and *nix use different characters for paths to files. In Windows, it is `\`, and in *nix it is `/`.

To make your code cross-platform compatible, you should consider using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). For example:

```
import os
print(os.path.join("queries", "prices.sql"))
```

This will give you "queries/prices.sql" on *nix, and "queries\prices.sql" on Windows.

Comment: Pretty sure Windows will also accept forward slashes in most cases (not on the command line, though, because it clashes with their options).

Comment: @L3viathan Windows might, but I would still recommend `os.path` regardless. It has a semantically descriptive name, is a widely tested library function, and if in the future the code is to be ported to some obscure OS with weird path names, it can still be extended easily.

Comment: I am in the process of deploying it with the changes but seems like it is the solution.